# Why does JSON.parse escape backslashes differently in Chrome and node?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-chrome

`> JSON.parse('["\\\\\\"\\"a\\""]');`

In Chromium, yields: `["\""a""]`.

In Node (8.6.0), yields: `['\\""a"']`.

The result is the same whether or not the result is passed through `console.log`, or stored in variable and then logged.

What is the reason for the difference?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` doesn't escape anything.  You're seeing differences in `console.log()`.

Comment: ^ `console.log` is is not standardized.